# Segmentation fault with access to field using virtual pure function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, pure-virtual, pure-function

I read a lot about the error with pure virtual call, but i didn't figure out what's wrong with my code:

I programmed Chess game, using polymorphism.

here some code:

Piece.hpp (the Parent for all game pieces)

```
class Piece
{
private:
    char _player;
    virtual int isMoveLegalForSpecificPiece(int positionRow, int positionCol, int targetRow,
                                            int targetCol, Piece *board[8][8]) = 0;
public:
    ~Piece()
    {
    }
    Piece(char player);
    virtual int isMoveLegal(int positionRow, int positionCol, int targetRow, int targetCol,
                            Piece *board[8][8]);
    char getPlayer();
    virtual char getSign() const = 0;
    virtual std::string getUnicodeSymbol() const = 0;
};
```

Rook.hpp (for example)

```
#include "Piece.hpp"

class Rook : public virtual Piece {
private:
    std::string _unicode = "265C";
    virtual int isMoveLegalForSpecificPiece(int positionRow, int positionCol, int targetRow,
                                            int targetCol, Piece *board[8][8]);
public:
    Rook(char player) : Piece(player){}
    ~Rook() {}
    virtual std::string getUnicodeSymbol() const;
    char getSign() const;
};
```

and Rook.cpp

```
#include "Rook.hpp"
char Rook::getSign() const {return 'r';}
int Rook::isMoveLegalForSpecificPiece(int positionRow, int positionCol, int targetRow,
                                      int targetCol, Piece *board[8][8]) {
    if (positionRow == targetRow) {
        int rightOrLeft = (targetCol - positionCol > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        for (int i = positionCol + rightOrLeft; i != targetCol; i += rightOrLeft) {
            if (board[positionRow][i] != 0) {return 0;  }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else if (positionCol == targetCol)  {
        int upOrDown = (targetRow - positionRow > 0) ? 1 : -1;
        for (int i = positionRow + upOrDown; i != targetRow; i += upOrDown) {
            if (board[i][positionCol] != 0) {return 0;}
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
std::string Rook::getUnicodeSymbol() const {return _unicode;}
```

Board::Board()

```
Board::Board()  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        board[1][i] = new Pawn('w');
        board[6][i] = new Pawn('b');
    }   
    board[7][0] = new Rook('b');
    board[0][0] = new Rook('w');
    board[7][1] = new Knight('b');
    board[0][1] = new Knight('w');
    board[7][2] = new Bishop('b');
    board[0][2] = new Bishop('w');
    board[7][3] = new King('b');
    board[0][3] = new King('w');
    board[7][4] = new Queen('b');
    board[0][4] = new Queen('w');
    board[7][5] = new Bishop('b');
    board[0][5] = new Bishop('w');
    board[7][6] = new Knight('b');
    board[0][6] = new Knight('w');
    board[7][7] = new Rook('b');
    board[0][7] = new Rook('w');
}
```

Board::print

```
void Board::print() {
    printRowLetters();
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
        cout << (char) ('1' + i) << " ";
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            string isColor = "0";
            string pieceUnicode = " ";
            if (board[i][j])    {
                isColor = (board[i][j]->getPlayer() == 'w') ? "37" : "30";
                pieceUnicode = board[i][j]->getUnicodeSymbol();
            }
        //some more code..
        }
    }
}
```

i'm stuck in that line:

> pieceUnicode = board[i][j]->getUnicodeSymbol();

i get:

> pure virtual method called

i didn't call the function within constructor or destructor

After putting the `virtual` keyword to the above `~Piece()` destructor, this problem was solved. But now on same line i get

> Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)

any ideas?

here some more info:

i declare board inside main of chess.cpp:

> Board boardGame;

then i send to void playGame(Board boardGame) like this:

> playGame(boardGame);

and inside i send to void getNextMove(Board board, string whitePlayer, string blackPlayer) like this:

> getNextMove(boardGame, whitePlayer, blackPlayer);

and then i'm using:

> boardGame.print();

Comment: TL;DR; Make destructors of abstract classes `virtual`: `virtual ~Piece() {}`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks! now i get Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault). any idea?

Comment: @AviadLevy Out of bounds access anywhere (looks likely)?

Comment: how is `board` declared?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can it be a problem with the return type of getUnicodeSymbol()?
if im debugging it says: Cannot access memory at adrees 0x0

Comment: _@AviadLevy_ I think @Luchian should ressurect his answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ neah, he initializes all elements to null and then checks `if board[i][j]` so it should work.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore i declare board inside main of chess.cpp:
Board boardGame;
then i send to void playGame(Board boardGame) like this:
playGame(boardGame);
and inside i send to void getNextMove(Board board, string whitePlayer, string blackPlayer)like this:
getNextMove(boardGame, whitePlayer, blackPlayer);
and then i'm using:
boardGame.print();

Comment: @AviadLevy [Improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27676586/edit) whith new informations, for heaven's sake.

Comment: @AviadLevy The question title is pretty misleading now. Always ask questions here, so they're helpful for future researchers about your problem.

Comment: @AviadLevy Very basic -- your `Piece` class lacks a virtual destructor.  If you deallocate the memory for the pieces, your program will exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have an object of type `Board` and you make copies of it, yet you don't have a copy constructor, and I also assume `Board::board` is dynamically allocated.

[This will cause problems with copying, assignment or destroying. (Read me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

You need to obey the rule of three and provide valid implementations for the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor of `Board`.

Or you could declared `Board::board` as a vector of pointers and not worry about the memory management.

This is all based on an assumption, if you already do this then this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: thanks! just to make sure i understood:
i need to build copy constructor to Board, because when i send him from function to function, the data its hold is lost

Comment: @AviadLevy well... not really - read the linked answer for details. When you pass by value, you make a shallow copy, and when the function exits, the copy is deleted, which deletes the members if it has a destructor.

Comment: thanks! i think understood!
will try, and report later.

Comment: that was the problem! thanks for helping